# Use client hostnames for DNS

Tags: dns

I want to set up a DNS server on my network. I want to keep it simple and just use `$(hostname -s).catpants.lan` as the DNS entry for each system on my network. Internal DNS only.

Is there a way I can make each of my systems automatically tell the DNS server their hostname and IP? Or do I have to edit a config on my DNS server every time I spin up a new vm? Is there a name for this particular way of doing DNS?

To keep it simple, all systems on my network are running Linux.

Comment: DHCP might be worth a look, but I'm actually not sure in which direction the hostname info flows.

Comment: I believe there are clients that will do dynamic DNS for nameservers like BIND, but I don't know much about that.  You might be interested in [AVAHI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avahi_%28software%29).  It's an auto host-name advertising service that runs on your local network.  When setup, it Just Works.  It's also built into MacOS, and there's a simple Windows client available from Apple to bring the third OS into the mix.  If you install avahi-daemon, you should soon be able to `ssh machinea` from machineb, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the ISC DHCP client (dhcp-client on Debian, Ubuntu, etc.) then you most definitely can set the hostname via /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf.  On recent versions, this is accomplished by:

```
    send host-name = gethostname();
```

On earlier versions, you had to hardcode the hostname in the directive.

I'm not so sure about setting the IP address through the DHCP lease process, but there is a "fixed-address" directive in the dhclient.conf which would appear to do what you want.  See the dhclient.conf manpage.